# adverbs that contain the same meaning that's already in the verb of a sentence

Tags: verbs, adverbs, sentence, syntactic-analysis, writing

I am reading William Zinsser's book "On Writing Well". In it he writes:

"But the secret of good writing is to strip every sentence to its cleanest components. Every word that serves no function, every long word that could be a short word, **every adverb that carries the same meaning that's already in the verb**, every passive construction that leaves the reader unsure of who is doing what - these are the thousand and one adulterants that weaken the strength of a sentence."

I am not sure what he means by adverbs that contain the same meaning that's already in the verb. Please provide me with examples of this and tips on how to avoid it. My goal is to learn how to identify instances where this happens and fix them.

Comment: I think it means things like the *loudly* in "Bob shouted loudly."

Comment: '... every adverb that carries a meaning that's already demanded by the verb'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say to an absolute certainty, but from the context you gave it sounds like you shouldn't use an adverb that defines the verb.

> He quickly sprinted across the courtyard.

In this example, we have the adverb **quickly** and the verb **sprinted**. In this case, you can't sprint without being quick about it, making it redundant. If you were to say:

> He girlishly sprinted across the courtyard.

This adds information to the sentence and gives you wonderful imagery. Basically, he's saying to only use words and phrases that give value to your writing; you can't sprint without being quick, it's implied.

Comment: Ah! If I say "he slowly crawled" that would be poor writing. I should say "he crawled". What if there are several sprinters and one is Usain Bolt? If I want to use an adverb to imply his sprinting is faster than the others how would I do that without breaking Zinsser's rule? Or should I not use an adverb to do that?

Comment: @anang You can definitely use an adverb. It's up to your judgment. If you think that the adverb adds to the sentence, by all means, use it. When you're dealing with hyperbole or extremism metaphors and analogies work well. "He turned on the last leg of the race; all you could see was blur below his torso. He was a gazelle among sloths."

Comment: Your gazelle among sloths line made me laugh. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

"One day as I sat musing
Alone and Melancholy and without a friend,
There came a voice from out of the gloom,
Saying, ‘Cheer up! Things might be worse.’"

While the verb [muse](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/muses) itself has the meaning to think or meditate in silence as on some subject, the part *"Alone and Melancholy and without a friend"* (the adverbial phrases) seems redundant and can be omitted.

Adverbs in sentences like "He **staggered**  toward the door **unsteadily**" or "He **dashed** out **hastily**" carry the meaning of the verbs they modify.